# Showing data on pages, wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I've read the wordpress hierarchy and I sort of do but also don't understand it.

What I don't get is how to show data on a page, as in where do I type my code to show it.

I've received a presset-setup from someone and have a few pages with the following on it.

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) :
      while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
   <?php the_title(); ?>
   <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

This would show data on the pages I create on wordpress I suppose?

But how would u get information on a page like in normal php, whereas you make a page called info.php and just echo whatever you want. (I'm a beginner at wordpress, so sorry for my misunderstanding).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wordpress uses templated pages. So for example `index.php` will represent the home page, page.php will represent the pages on your site and `single.php` will be used when viewing single posts. You need to edit the relevant template in your theme folder to make a change. Bearing in mind if you change `page.php` for example, all pages will appear differently with your changes. So you are affecting multiple pages.

If you want to edit a single page, you can make a page template. Call it `info.php` and then select a page/multiple pages to use this template.

See this link on creating a template page and assigning a page to it.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates

In short though you create the page `info.php`, drop this into your theme folder. Put this code into the file.

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Any Name Here
*/
```

Then on the page in the dashboard you should see template on the right, which you can then change the chosen template. In this case in the dropdown you would see "Any name Here"

If for example you wanted to create an independent page, then in the very root of your Wordpress install (not the theme folder), create say a folder called test and in here create `info.php`. You should then be able to navigate to www.yoursite.com/test/info.php. This is obviously separated entirely from Wordpress.